# For which vector is there no solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, systems-of-equations

We have the vector $$\vec{v}_1=\begin{pmatrix}3 \\ 2 \\ -1 \\ 5\end{pmatrix}  , \ \ \vec{v}_2=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 6 \\ 2 \\ 7\end{pmatrix}$$ I want to find a vector $\vec{w}$ for that there are no $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a\vec{v}_1+b\vec{v}_2=\vec{w}$.

For that do we calculate the rank for $A=\begin{pmatrix}3 & 0 \\ 2 & 6 \\ -1 & 2 \\ 5 & 7\end{pmatrix}$ and for $(A\mid \vec{w})=\begin{pmatrix}3 & 0 & w_1 \\ 2 & 6 & w_2 \\ -1 & 2 & w_3\\ 5 & 7 & w_4\end{pmatrix}$ and get the conditio that these two results have to be different?

Or is there also an other way?

Comment: Just row reduce your augmented matrix and since the coefficient matrix has rank at most $2$, so you will get expressions in the right most columns such that if they are not zero then the system is inconsistent and you will get your $\vec{w}$.

Comment: Row reduction . The determinant has to be nonzero.

Comment: We cannot calculate the determinant, we have more rows than columns, can we? @Bernard

Comment: So you mean to use the rank, or not? @AnuragA

Comment: Sorry, I misread and thought we were in $\mathbf R^3$. So forget about  the determinant. However, row reduction will yield the conditions that ensure  rank is $3$ – and also the equations of the subspace generated by $\vec v_2=1$ and $\vec v_2$ when the rank is $2$.

Comment: @MaryStar we don't really need to calculate the rank. The reason I mentioned it was to guarantee existence of such a vector. Though one can claim the same without using the rank directly, just by saying that we have two vectors in $\Bbb{R}^4$ so we can always find a vector outside the span of these two vectors. I have written a solution (below) that could be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to find quickly a vector that is not a linear combination of $\vec{v}_1$ and $\vec{v}_2$, then you can just construct a vector which is orthogonal to $\vec{v}_1$ and $\vec{v}_2$.

With 
$$\vec{v}_1=\begin{pmatrix}3 \\ 2 \\ -1 \\ 5\end{pmatrix}  , \ \ \vec{v}_2=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 6 \\ 2 \\ 7\end{pmatrix}$$

Looking at $\vec{v}_2$, you can take, for example, $\vec{w}=\begin{pmatrix}x \\ -1 \\ 3 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$. Use $\vec{v}_1$ to find $x$:
$$3x + 2(-1) + (-1)3 + 0\cdot 5 =0 \Leftrightarrow x = \frac{5}{3}$$
$$\Rightarrow \vec{w}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac 53 \\ -1 \\ 3 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} \mbox{ is such a vector.}$$

Comment: Aa so that there no solution the vectors $v_1, v_2, w$ have to be linear independent?

Comment: Exactly :-). So, it is.

Answer (score 0):

Let consider by RREF

$$\begin{pmatrix}3 &2&-1&5\\ 0  & 6  & 2 & 7\end{pmatrix}\to \begin{pmatrix}9 &0&-5&8\\ 0  & 6  & 2 & 7\end{pmatrix}$$

therefore $w_1=(0,0,1,0)$ or $w_2=(0,0,0,1)$ or any $w=aw_1+bw_2$ are good choice.

Comment: How did you calculate that?

Comment: @MaryStar By the RREF we see the the two given vectors have pivots in the first and second position, therefore any $w$ as those proposed is linearly independent from them. It is the more effective way to obtain a linearly independent $w$.

Answer (score 0):

We can show that 
$$(A\mid \vec{w})=\begin{bmatrix}3 & 0 & w_1 \\ 2 & 6 & w_2 \\ -1 & 2 & w_3\\ 5 & 7 & w_4\end{bmatrix} \xrightarrow{\text{row reduced }} \begin{bmatrix}3 & 0 & w_1 \\ 0 & 6 & w_2-\frac{2}{3}w_1 \\ 0 & 0 & w_3-\frac{1}{3}w_2+\frac{5}{9}w_1\\ 0 & 0 & w_4-\frac{7}{6}w_2-\frac{8}{9}w_1\end{bmatrix}.$$
So for **inconsistency**, you want at least one of the bottom two entries in the right hand column to be non-zero, i.e.
$$\text{either } \quad w_3-\frac{1}{3}w_2+\frac{5}{9}w_1 \neq 0 \quad \text{ or } \quad w_4-\frac{7}{6}w_2-\frac{8}{9}w_1 \neq 0.$$
For example we can have $\vec{w}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$